# How to implement concurrent programming between simulink and matlab

Tags: concurrency, buffer, simulink

I need help for the following situation.

My project is to use simulink to simulate a robot.The output of the simulink model are robbot's position and torques at each timestep. My problem is on the data collection part. I plan to use a buffer to store the simulink output and use antoher matalb function to access the same buffer to get the data out of the buffer for online data analysis. The requirement is the simulink model and matlab data analysis function need to run simultaneously. And the matalb data analysis function decide when to get the data out of the buffer. This is like a producer-consumer problem, where the simulink is the producer and the data analysis matlab function acts as a consumer.

My question is how to protect the buffer for mutual exclusion. I do not want to use To workspace block, because it only updates data when simulink is paused or stopped. I do not find any smeaphore or mutex like structure provided by matalb or simulink. I have tried the following ways to solve the problem, but non of them works:

1. I have tried to use the queue and buffer block in DSP toolbox, this two blocks provides mutual exclusion, but the size of the output data is changed during the simulation. Basically when the matlab function collecting data, it takes all the data stored in the buffer at the moment. Then buffer block seems to output one by one at each simulink timestep.
2. I have tried to implement a queue by a persist variable in a embedded function. When the matalb function want to collect data, it flip a signal flag to tell the simulink to output the data into workspace. But in this method, the matalb function have to get the data by two calls. The 1st call to flip the flag and then return. In the next, the 2nd call is used to search the workspace to find the data outputted by simulink. This method is denied by my advisor, because it is not elegant.

I think RTW may solve this problem, but the simulink model and matalb analysis function code are often changed, so for debugging purpose, I plan to not change the simulink in to C/C++. But I wonder whether I can use C to implement a mutex and call by simulink and Matlab. If the answer is yes, then how to do this?

I really hope someone can help me out. Any suggestion is appreciated. By the way, I am using Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Access Block Data During Simulation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/accessing-block-data-during-simulation.html) in the Simulink documentation and also at [Simulink Signal Viewing using Event Listeners and a MATLAB UI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24294-simulink-signal-viewing-using-event-listeners-and-a-matlab-ui) on the File Exchange. I think this will do what you want.